# ElasticSearch Highlighting not doing what I would expect

Tags: elasticsearch

I added highlighting into my Elasticsearch queries, however, it appears to be highlighting on fields that I don't think it should.

This is my query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "entityName.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span class=\"highlighter\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "entityName": {},
      "friendlyUrl": {},
      "sentBy": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": true
  },
  "query": {"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"test","operator":"and"}}}]}},
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serviceId": "0b6d064d-1430-4b04-99f7-c30dc03860fc"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionId": "a29f30e6-f44b-42cc-82c4-f7cb98cb44ef"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionType": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "entityType": [
              "4"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a line on my server that adds the highlighting:

```
 desc.Highlight(h => h.PreTags("<span class=\"highlighter\">").PostTags("</span>").OnFields(ff => ff.OnField("entityName"), fff => fff.OnField("friendlyUrl"), x => x.OnField("sentBy")));
```

This query should find any documents that matches the Wildcard `john*` and the Regexp `.*` on the `keywords` field (I need to check for `keywords != ""`). The problem is when the results come back, the highlighter response comes back and **highlights everything in the documents**.

It's as if the regexp is ignoring the fact that I told it to only look at the `keywords` field and is instead matching on all fields.  I would expect the highlighter to only highlight the `keywords` field if it matches `.*`, but it is not...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"require_field_match": true` to your highlighter to force it to match on the queried fields.

Comment: I read about this already, but the docs say the default is `true`, so I didn't think this would matter. I will still try it out just in case though.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#field-match

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So I added that and it did make the highlighting go away for this query, however it seemed to also make it go away for all my other queries as well... Now nothing comes back with highlighting even though it should.

Comment: Hm, can you provide the current full query?

Comment: Yeah let me try to get it using Fiddler. Half of my query is done client side, half is done server side (C#) so I don't have easy access to it.

Comment: I added the full query above. It returns 1 document that has a match for "test" in the "entityName" field. Therefore it should have a highlight for "entityName", however there are none.

Comment: That's a completely different query. You search on `_all`, `serviceId`, `subscriptionId`, `subscriptionType`, `entityType`. There is no `entityName` field you search on.

Comment: Oh I would have expected "_all" to highlight on all fields. Let me try a test to specifically look at just 1 field and see if that works

Comment: Add a custom query just for `entityName` field, or change the main query itself: `"highlight":{"pre_tags":["<span class=\"highlighter\">"],"post_tags":["</span>"],"fields":{"entityName":{"highlight_query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"entityName":{"query":"test","operator":"and"}}}]}}},"friendlyUrl":{},"sentBy":{}}}`

Comment: Thanks, I switched over to use "entityName" and it now highlights.. Interesting... it is unfortuneate that I lose my ability to easily search across all fields. Do you know if a Multimatch query would work?

Comment: Yes, if the `multi_match` will use `entityName` or any wildcard field name, like `entityN*` for example.